# Converting NSString into NSDAte once again

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

i have a label which is :

```
_labelCell.text = [2014-06-22 20:27:48 +0000];
```

What i want to do is to convert this string into NSDate so i can format it into something like : EEEE dd MM yyyy

i try :

```
    // convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+0000'"];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", dte);
```

but it always give me a NULL NSDate

Can someone help me on this little thing ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How is the NSString instance "str" being created? Please post that code for us.

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your date formatter is expecting a `T` in between the date and time. It returns `null` because there the string has a space instead of a `T`.

You're also missing a space before the timezone.

Fix those two issues, and it should work:

```
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss '+0000'";
```

Beware this might give you the wrong date, because of time zone issues. Test that out, and if it doesn't work adjust accordingly with `dateFormat.timeZone = ...`

Comment: @user2335528 - You are taking very poor advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your date format needs to resemble the format of the date.  See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns for the format patterns.  For your date `2014-06-22 20:27:48 +0000` you need to use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ".  Note that it must be "yyyy", not "YYYY", and the zone field should be parsed rather than treated as a literal.  There is no "T" separating date and time.

Comment: It works perfectly fine with YYYY, and how to handle the timezone depends... I wouldn't assume +0000 is correct, that's a business logic question. Many systems I've dealt with will give you 0 as the timezone when in fact it is in some other timezone.

Comment: It does *not* "work perfectly" with YYYY.  Try it around the end of the year and you will discover this.